# If $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g_k(x)=g(x) \text{, and } \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g_k^{'}(x)=f(x) \text{ a.e.}$ show $g^{'}(x)=f(x) \text{ a.e.}$

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, absolute-continuity

Suppose $\{g_k(x)\}$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$, and for all $k$,

$$|g_k^{\prime}(x)| \le F(x) \text{ a.e.}$$

where $F(x) \in L^1[a,b]$. If

$$
 \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g_k(x) = g(x) \text{, and }
  \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g_k^{\prime}(x) = f(x) \text{ a.e.}
$$

prove that
$$g^{\prime}(x) = f(x) \text{ a.e.}$$

Alright, I'm tired of going in circles on this problem.  I know, since $\{g_k(x)\} $ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$ that

$$g_k(x) = \int_a^x g_k^\prime(t) \, dt + g_k(a)$$

What I'm trying to do is let $k \rightarrow \infty$ and then use the dominated convergence theorem to show that $g^{\prime}(x) = f(x) \text{ a.e.}$.  Can I simply take limits on both sides of the equality...then

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g_k(x) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}
  \left( \int_a^x g_k^\prime(t) \, dt + g_k(a) \right) \Rightarrow$$

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g_k(x) = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}
  \left( \int_a^x g_k^\prime(t) \, dt \right) + \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g_k(a) \Rightarrow$$

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g_k(x) = \int_a^x \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g_k^\prime(t) \, dt + \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} g_k(a) \Rightarrow$$

Then using the hypothesis:
$$g(x) = \int_a^x f(x) dt + g(a)$$

But where to go from here?  Do I just differentiate both sides and use the dominated convergence theorem or can I just claim the conclusion here via the dominated convergence theorem?

All help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rough Reasoning:**

Define the measure $\mu$ on $[a,b]$ as $\mu((c,d))=g(d)-g(c)$, then $\mu((c,d))=\displaystyle\int_{c}^{d}f(x)dx$ as what the reasoning has written, then $\dfrac{d\mu}{dx}=f(x)$ a.e.

However, we know that $\dfrac{d\mu}{dx}=g'(x)$ a.e. by an application of Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem.

**Another Reasoning?**

We have $\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{1}{|(c-\delta,c+\delta)|}\displaystyle\int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta}f(x)dx=f(c)$ for a.e. $c$ in $[a,b]$. But $\dfrac{g(c+\delta)-g(c-\delta)}{2\delta}=\dfrac{1}{|(c-\delta,c+\delta)|}\displaystyle\int_{c-\delta}^{c+\delta}f(x)dx$ and $g$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$, so $g$ is differentiable a.e. so $g'(c)=f(c)$ a.e. in $[a,b]$.

Comment: Thank you but what happens with g(x) on the left hand side of the equation?  How would the dominated convergence theorem play a factor?

Comment: Actually I don't really understand your question, can you be more specific?

Comment: I understand your question, the justification of swiping the limit and integral is by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem because of the dominated integrable function $F$.

Comment: What I'm asking is what happens with the $g(a)$ on the left hand side of the integral in my last equation $g(x) = \int_a^x f(x) dt + g(a)$.  p.s.  And I really appreciate your help!  I understand the rest of what you wrote.

Comment: Then we have $g(x)-g(a)=\displaystyle\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$, so $g$ is a primitive of $f$ by definition.

Comment: I get it!  Outstanding...

Comment: I just realized that what I have done is almost redundant, actually a theorem says that for that form of primitive, it is differentiable a.e. and equals to the integrand. So your last step actually goes to the final result by organizing something like $g(x)-g(a)$ as what I have written in the last comment.